# Command history for specific file

Tags: autocmd, command-history

Is it possible to find `:commands` entered while editing a specific file, as opposed to all commands ever typed at the `:` prompt? Failing that, is it possible to auto-save commands to a separate history while editing a certain file?

I've tried up-arrow and `q:`. I've viewed `viminfo` but at a first glance it seems to save all commands in one chunk.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it's not possible, AFAIK. Some commands manipulate the current buffer contents, but some don't. So Vim makes a difference between, say, "commands" and "search patterns", but not between "buffer #1"-commands and "buffer #2"-commands.
2. In principle, it's possible: trap `BufEnter` and `BufLeave` and use `histadd()`, `histdel()`, `histget()` and `histnr()` to do something useful.

Still looks pretty unnecessary job to me. Many buffers may earn from sharing the history with other buffers.

Comment: Needle in a haystack problem, other times "how TF did I delete that snippet". Thanks!